Unable to Reference WCF Web Service
I'm trying to add a service reference to an AJAX-enabled WCF Web Service from a C# Class Library.  I perform the following steps:

Right click "Service References" under the client-side class library
in Solution Explorer
Select "Add Server Reference..."
Click "Discover"
Try to expand "SampleWebService.svc" (which is my web service which appeared in the left-hand-side list from step 3)
As a result I now get the following error message in the bottom section of this dialog:


An error (Details) occurred while attempting to find services at 'https://localhost:44300/SampleWebService.svc'.

I click "Details" and get the following error message:

There was an error downloading 'https://localhost:44300/SampleWebService.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://localhost:44300/SampleWebService.svc'.
There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost:44300/SampleWebService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.


How do I get to the InnerException?

This problem is usually due to a problem with your service. You need to check if your service code is working. You'll need to provide a service code so we can help you solve the problem.
